# Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/ec2-user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` exited with 37

Tags: jenkins

when i try start jenkins after successfully installed jenkins (brew services start jenkins-lts) its not working, throwing error like

Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/ec2-user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` exited with 37.

please advise

Comment: did you found a solution ? i have the same issue ?

Comment: Same issue.....

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. The issue was resolved by;

- Restarting my laptop
- The run `brew services start jenkins-lts` to start Jenkins
- Then access `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issues.Then I try to restart my macbook and use this command 'brew services list' on terminal that shows the services had already started, which is said it works after restart.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).